# JSON, Safari, Ajax problems

Tags: ajax, json, safari

I am doing an Ajax call using jquery's $.ajax method, but in Safari I am not getting the correct response headers returned.

When looking at the 'Network' section of the 'Web Inspector' the headers are being placed in the 'Content' section for some strange reason...

Note: We are pulling the headers and JSON formatted data from our own web server, it fails in Safari and works great in FF, IE and Chrome etc.

Here is what I am seeing.

```
 HTTP/1.11
 Server: Vision
 Content-Type: application/json
 Accept-Ranges: bytes
 Content-Length: 134

 {
 "channels" : 1,
 "channelInfo" : [
 {
 "channelNo" : 0,
 "name" : "Humidity",
 "units" : "%RH",
 "max" : 100.0,
 "min" : 0.0
 }]
 }
```

If I place the same code on a live external web server the page loads fine and the headers appear fine in all browsers including Safari!

So from this I can only assume that I am retrieving something different from our own web server that is not the same as on an external apache web server!

Does anyone have any ideas why my headers and JSON content are appearing in the 'Content' section of the web inspector in Safari?

Hope this makes sense?